# Youtube data API V3: Is 100000 the maximum number of items that can be retrieved with playlistItems.lsit?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to fetch all the videos uploaded on a Youtube channel (which has more than 600K videos) via Youtube data api V3, using a combination of the playlistItems.list and Videos.list methods. My code returns when I reach 100K videos - but I could not find anything about this limit in the official documentation (my quotas are not exhausted). Could someone confirm this?

Answer (score 1):

This hard limit of Google API methods is not documented but can be seen by making a request to most of the YouTube methods. Now i dont have a play list with that many videos.  So I used videos.search as an example

For example Videos.search [Apis exporter](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&_h=3&) with no search parm should in theory return all of the videos on YouTube. If you check the `totalResults` field in the response you will see `1000000` so the max number of videos you can get back from youtube will be in this method 1,000,000.

Response

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/c9K0gDBrP1-D2Zr4IhYolPQ8r3k\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
 "regionCode": "DK",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1000000,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
```

totalResults is the total number of rows returned by a method.  regardless of the number of pages there will be.   So if your total resuts is 100000 and you know you have 600000 then i would suggest that this is the limit of the API.

Quota is the limit is a to how many requests your application can make and this is unrelated to the number of rows that a method itself will return. If you are getting a quota error you would know it.  Its normally one of the 403 errors relating to [Limit](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors)

You have not mentioned you are getting an error so i would suggest that this is not a quota issue but a limit with in the api yourself an there is no way you can change that.